# Display temporary message in terminal that is not stored in terminal history

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to create a command line password file decryption script that would reveal the contents of an encrypted file in a terminal window for a maximum of say 10 seconds, after which point the text is automatically cleared.

I'm not really sure what the correct terminology for this sort of functionality would be, so sorry if the answer is available via the correct search string.

Comment: just for clarity - you want to be able to `print` something to the terminal but not have it logged in the terminal logs? if so - this is not possible, as the simple act of `print` which is the functionality with which you output to the terminal, creates a log - however, you could work around this by either making the log iteself temporary, or by outputing your content to a different location instead of the terminal, such as a pop-up/toast (although they have their own logging methods). in short - it is impossible to do exactly what you ask - and very hard to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `curses` module. [This sample script](http://www.ironalbatross.net/wiki/index.php5?title=Python_Curses#First_Curses_script) seems to do pretty much what you want.

Comment: I don't have to use `print`, I know there are plenty of other terminal applications which have the ability to modify their output after the fact, I'm hoping this is not something terribly complex. For instance, something like `apt-get update` which modifies the percentage of the current line and then finishes on a final confirmation message. If you press Enter during the output of multiple lines, the current line is abandoned in it's current state and progress of the current item resumes on the next line.

Comment: @omz thanks, that actually rings a bell, will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to display one line of "secret" output, you could use "carriage return" and overwrite the line. It does not leave any traces in the terminal history.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import sys

print("hello", end = '')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
print("\rxxxxx")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the terminal with [ansi escape sequences](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html). This works on almost every terminal emulator (except the win32 console).

```
import time
import sys

print '\x1b[0;0H\x1b[2J' # home cursor, clear screen
print 'terribly secret file contents'
time.sleep(2)
print '\x1b[2J'
sys.stdout.flush() # flush output buffer.
```

However, if the output of your program is redirected to a file it will be captured nonetheless.

Additionally, you might have to disable the terminal's scrollback buffer.